# elements moving side after setting them on the other side in android studio when lunching the app

Tags: xml, android-studio, layout

I have an issue with my xml where when I start the app on my phone elements will switch sides even though they are constrained, while on the computer its fine.
this how my xml starts and after that I just added itemViews buttons and ImageViews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OfflineGameTable">
```

this is how i did an image view

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/OfflineTablePlayerImage1"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.82"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

Comment: You probably want to use "app:srcCompat" attribute instead of "tools:srcCompat"

Comment: I switched it and add a picture but it still the same(still have the issue)